# Looking to replace a button onclick with a different size button in a slightly different position

Tags: html, css

Here's a link to a couple the buttons I'm starting with:

[image: http://imgur.com/DrpgE]

I'm trying to make it seem like the buttons are physically pressed down when they're clicked on, so that would mean removing the original button image, and replacing it with a button image without a drop shadow.  To get it to look right, I'll need to move the new shadow-less button down and to the right so it aligns with where the shadow was of the original button.  Because the shadow is transparent, I can't just hide the shadow-less button underneath.

I've seen tutorials for button changes, but they all seem to use the hiding technique.

Any ideas?

Comment: My first question would be, why are you using images?  Can you share some what you already have (html/css)?  It looks like you could do this without images or JavaScript.

Comment: i'm with @FakeRainBrigand - should be doable without JS, and probably also without images - but let's see some code first...

Comment: I'm a beginner, so if there is another way to go about doing this without images, I'm unaware of it.  I haven't really attempted much yet because I didn't want to set off in the wrong direction... but I guess it's too late for that :/ Anyway, here's what I have so far... It's just my table and some CSS to style it.

Comment: Sorry, the character limit won't allow me to post my code.  This is my first time here.

Comment: @greg you need to edit your post to add your code. There's an `edit` link under your post beside the `link` ...link

Comment: Ohhh, ok.  I have a link to my website below in response to Mr. H's answer in the mean time.  I'm going to try a few things later tonight and I'll be sure to edit my OP.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this used to be a huge question of mine.

First of all let me say I think you need to lose the idea of actually "moving" the button.
I'd say the best way to create that *illusion* would be to simply make two different pictures (of the same size), one with the button pressed.

The only thing you need then is a way of deciding which picture to show.
If you want to make hover buttons, I found a very pretty and simple way of making those using CSS.
You could make your button an <a> and give it a class (for example "mybutton").
In your CSS you will have not one, but two blocks of code for it:

```
a.mybutton {
background: transparent url(/*image A url here*/) no-repeat left;
}

a.mybutton:hover, a.mybutton:active {
background: transparent url(/*image B url here*/) no-repeat right;
}
```

This way, when you hover over the link, the last block will take effect, overrule the first one, and the image (which I made a background) will change from A to B.

It's important to also give the button a `width` and `height`, because otherwise you won't see it(!). You only need to do that in the top block.

Also you might notice that if you hover over it for the first time, image B will have to load, making it flicker.
Now there are lots of dirty JavaScripts that can fix this, but the way I solve this problem is by merging image A and B into the same file and making the background shift from left to right (or top to bottom, whatever suits you best) when hovering.
This would give you something like:

```
a.mybutton {
background: transparent url(/*image url here*/) no-repeat left;
}

a.mybutton:hover, a.mybutton:active {
background: transparent url(/*image url here*/) no-repeat right;
}
```

Now I don't know exactly when you want the pushing effect to take place, but even if you would want to make something more complicated than hover buttons, I'd say using CSS to change the background image of the button would be the way.

It might be an idea for you to read this page at [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp).

A website in which I used above techniques for the buttons is [didyoueverfeel.com](http://www.didyoueverfeel.com).

Comment: I really appreciate that write up.  Thank you.  I tried it, but it didn't work out.  Maybe because I have my buttons in an HTML table?  I tried removing the table, but everything quickly turned into a giant mess.  I was in a bit of a rush, so I just hosted the website anyway, figured I'll just get back to the buttons later.  Here's the site anyway if you want to see the code: http://californiasodcenter.com

Comment: Hi greg,

I've taken a look at your link.
Having the buttons in a table shouldn't be a problem.
I personally prefer using an unordered list (`<ul>`) for such things, but I don't think any button has ever cared.

Back to your page: the reason you can't change the images using CSS is probably that you're using `<img>` elements to show them.
In my example there are no `<img>` elements. Instead, the button pictures are backgrounds of the `<a>` elements.

Comment: Maybe you could try again with above things in mind. Don't forget to give the `<a>` elements a `width` and `height` in your CSS, corresponding to the button image size.

Comment: Also important: I like how clean your code looks, but there are some minor mistakes.
For example the `<title>` element should be inside the `<head>` element and you forgot to close most of the `<a>` tags in the menu.
Did you know you can validate your HTML using the W3C Validator?

I also noticed that you gave the `<div>` containing your button table a `class="button"` attribute.
That's unusual, because the `<a>` elements inside it already are "buttons".
Instead I would suggest going with something like `id="menu"`.

Good luck.

W3C Validator about your page: http://tinyurl.com/d4pg5rm

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips.  I'm going to try again later tonight after I get some studying in for my classes and I'll post the results.  I definitely did not know I could do that with the W3C Validator (or that there was even such a thing), I'll try to get that all cleaned up.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Yay, it worked!  Thank you!  The validator is still picking up some errors, and the color/style of the buttons/bar looks a little weird to me, but that's all stuff I can tinker with later.  I guess there's always something.  Thanks again though, I never would have guessed that I could get so excited over buttons.

Comment: You're very welcome.

To give you a hint on the errors: you kan only make lists (<ul>) of <li> elements, not of <a> elements. 
So you should have something like: <li><a href="url" class="button">text</a></li>

Good luck with it.